# XML string or object serialization?

Tags: c#, xml

Is it good to create a XML element just as string? For example:

```
string xmlString = $@"<methodCall>
<methodName>c.mail</methodName>
<params>
<param><value><string>{number}</string></value></param>
<param><value><string>{email}</string></value></param>
<param><value><i4>5</i4></value></param>
</params>
</methodCall>";
```

And to Load it with

```
doc.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));
XmlDeclaration xmlDec;
xmlDec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
xmlDec.Encoding = "UTF-8";

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
doc.InsertBefore(xmlDec, root);
```

(Inspired by MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmldeclaration.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Or could that cause any problems and I should create a object and serialize this? And when, how? Since using just a simple string is really fast, I would prefer this solution - but not if this is bad practice or could cause problems. (XML is new for me)

EDIT:

Why does this need more details? I think my question is clear?
For the people who are interested how I solved this. Thanks to the guide I changed the code to this:

```
#region root Node
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("methodCall");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
#endregion

#region XML Node Method name
XmlNode methodNameNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("methodName");
methodNameNode.InnerText = "customer.sendmail";
rootNode.AppendChild(methodNameNode);
#endregion


#region XML Parameters
XmlNode paramsNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("params");

#region Setting Number
XmlNode paramElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
XmlNode valueAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
XmlNode stringAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateElement("string");
stringAttribute.InnerText = number;
valueAttribute.AppendChild(stringAttribute);
paramElement.AppendChild(valueAttribute);
#endregion

#region Setting Email
XmlNode paramElement2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
XmlNode valueAttribute2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
XmlNode stringAttribute2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("string");
stringAttribute2.InnerText = email;
valueAttribute2.AppendChild(stringAttribute2);
paramElement2.AppendChild(valueAttribute2);
#endregion

#region Setting validation
XmlNode paramElement3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("param");
XmlNode valueAttribute3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("value");
XmlNode stringAttribute3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("i4");
stringAttribute3.InnerText = "5";
valueAttribute3.AppendChild(stringAttribute3);
paramElement3.AppendChild(valueAttribute3);
#endregion

#region Adding ISC, Email and vadlidation to paramsNode
paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement);
paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement2);
paramsNode.AppendChild(paramElement3);
rootNode.AppendChild(paramsNode);
#endregion

#endregion

#region Setting encoding to UTF8
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
xmlDeclaration.Encoding = "UTF-8";
//xmlDec.Standalone = "yes";
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
#endregion
```

This will give (as example) the following XML:

[image: XML example]

But I can really recommend to read the tutorial: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/

It helped me a lot to understand about XML.

Comment: *Every* code you write may cause errors. Of course it might produce problems under very specific conditions. However that highly depends on your surroundings. Apart from this there´s a reason that xml-parsers exist. It´s a pain to parse xml yourself, **allways** use any ready to use parser. Your code however allready uses an xml-parser. Depending on your data-structure and what you want to do with the objects it´s fine to do so.

Comment: I see. Do you mean I should use 'XElement.Parse' for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-parse-a-string

Comment: And another question: Why did MS have this in the docs when it is not safe?

Comment: @HimBromBeere "always" with one "L" .

Comment: Thought it would be easier. Thanks for your answers. I've found a tutorial which I think (regarding to your answers) I should read first: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this yourself is bad, no mater how you turn and look at it.

Example: What if your fields number or email contain characters that would need escaping in XML? Whoops, broken. So don't do this by hand. Get a tool. XML serialization is so easy in .NET that you should not bother thinking about it.

And building it by hand, *then using a serializer to deserialize it and put it in a serializer tree*? That's stupid. There is a serializer available, at least use it to build the XML. You don't need classes, but at least use it to write nodes and elements and get rid of formatting and escaping problems that way.

Comment: I understand your point but the escaping and type protecting happens earlier. I just pass them to the method which should create a XML. Do you mean a tool from nuget? Which one can you suggest?

Comment: "XML is new for me" -- definitely don't do it yourself. You don't even know what sort of issues you might encounter, or be creating for somebody else consuming your XML. I've encountered far too many examples of bad and just plain invalid "XML" to recommend anyone ever roll their own.

Comment: @user3772108 If escaping your data is handled by somebody else, that's not ideal either. Who but your XML serializer would know how to escape your data?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've found a tutorial which I think (regarding to your answers) I should read first: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/